# How to detect when Firefox has faked a network response?

Tags: firefox, fetch-api, browser-cache

My site shows users when data was last downloaded. After rebooting and reopening Firefox, when I had not yet started the webserver on localhost, my site in Firefox loads and shows data was `Loaded 0s ago`! Which is impossible! Opening the site in a second tab, Firefox confirms that the server is not running and that it gets a connection reset (TCP RST from the kernel).

Simplified, the code looks like this:

```js
let dataLoaded = null;
function loadData() {
  fetch(url).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((responsejson) => {
    dataLoaded = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
    // do a lot more stuff with the responsejson
  });
}
loadData();
setInterval(() => {
  if (dataLoaded == null) {
    $('#dataAge').innerText = '';
    return;
  }
  const now = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
  $('#dataAge').innerText = `Loaded ${now - dataLoaded}s ago`;
}, 15000);
```

`dataLoaded` is only set/filled in the XHR response handler. Firefox must be faking network traffic in order to get that variable set, because if the global `dataLoaded` variable (the page state) had been cached to disk, it would have been set to the old value and it would have reflected the data's correct age.

To confirm that theory, I set a breakpoint on the `dataLoaded = (new Date()).get...` line, restart Firefox, and: lo and behold, the breakpoint triggers! The `responsejson` object is complete and valid.

The network tab shows that the HTML and CSS were loaded from cache, but the fetched data is shown as "234.7KB (raced)". In the network tab, I can click the XHR and open the response tab, but in the Headers tab there are no response headers visible, so no way to tell the `Date`(time) on which that response was generated. The timings are all 0ms.

So... this is great and all, I am genuinely pleased that the data is restored without me having to stuff it in localStorage or similar and I am happy to keep that behavior, but how do I avoid lying to the user about how old this data is? What gives away that it was loaded from disk?

Edit: did more testing, the behavior can be disabled by passing `Math.random()` or `(new Date()).getTime()` as part of the URL. Presumably, Firefox doesn't find a match for that URL on disk and so it doesn't take the stored data and pass it back as a response. (Another approach is looking at the `Date` response header, but then one has to apply a heuristic based on clock skew rather than truly *knowing* whether it was a replayed response.) This does not resolve the question because I don't want to disable this helpful behavior to restore page state, I just want to know when it's happening such that the user can be informed.

Comment: What does `response.headers` tell you?

Comment: Is it possible for you to simply append the timestamp in the returned JSON directly? This would be the bullet proof solution. Otherwise might be worth looking at things like `performance.getEntriesByType("resource").find(({name}) => name === url)?.transferSize` (or maybe other properties of the PerfTiming object).

Comment: @Bergi That gives the correct response headers, so with the original old `Date` header. I could use that to detect the age, but clock imperfections (on either the server or the client side) make this a heuristic more than a binary method that can reliably tell one way or another. I don't see extra headers that give away that it's a cached response

Comment: @Kaiido a response timestamp will have a clock difference between the client and server. This was going to be my fallback solution (being able to tell to the precision of a few minutes at (typical) worst is better than nothing) if there is no way to actually tell. The performance API is something I didn't know about, that's worth looking into, thanks!

Comment: @Luc I might have expected some *missing* headers (probably cache-related ones) to give away whether it's cached or not. But if you have a `Date` http header anyway, I would recommend to just use that. Computers with internet access typically will have ntp synchronisation, so I wouldn't expect that time to be off by more than a few seconds, which seems to be good enough.

Comment: @Kaiido Just tested with transferSize, that works actually! It's zero for a cached response and nonzero for a live one. Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: But that won't tell you when the last cached response was received. Also, I'm not sure it's 100% bullet proof. I'd prefer if you posted an answer with what you end up using if that's not too much trouble for you.

Answer (score 0):

Original:

```js
fetch(url).then((response) => {
  return response.json();
}).then((responsejson) => {
  dataLoaded = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
  // do stuff with the responsejson
});
```

Solution, combined from own testing and [Kaliido's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77693745/detect-when-firefox-has-faked-a-network-response?noredirect=1#comment136976248_77693745):

```js
fetch(url).then((response) => {
  setTimeout(() => { // the performance stats are not available straight away
    dataLoaded = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
    // Thanks Kaiido for this line - ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77693745/detect-when-firefox-has-faked-a-network-response?noredirect=1#comment136976248_77693745
    let reqperf = performance.getEntriesByType("resource").find(({name}) => name === response.url);
    if (reqperf) {
      if (reqperf.transferSize == 0) {
          dataLoaded = -1;
      }
      showDataAge();
    }
    else {
      // Are there any browsers that need this? All allegedly support transferSize since March 2023. We can remove this else{} fallback method if it universally turns out to work
      fetch('cachedetector?' + (new Date()).getTime().toString()).catch(() => {
          dataLoaded = -1;
      }).finally(() => {
          showDataAge();
      });
    }
  }, 40); //1ms is not enough
  return response.json();
}).then((responsejson) => {
  // do stuff with the responsejson
});
```

The code to show the data's age now has an `if` clause for when `dataLoaded === -1`, in which case it shows "Loaded from cache". Otherwise, it shows something like "Loaded 0s ago" (scaling to minutes, hours, etc. as needed).

One could use `response.headers.get('Date')`, or a custom timestamp field in the server response, to determine the age in case a cached response is detected. This will have a slight clock difference to the local time, but should be good enough if you do not need precision to the second. If the browser can give you the cache time instead, that would be the perfect solution, but I do not know whether it can do that.

**Mechanism**

The solution works because the [`performance` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) shows how many bytes were transferred. Whereas the network tab in the developer tools will show you something like "235KB (raced)", the Javascript API will actually give you the correct value of 0 if it was from a cache that never hit the network.

As a fallback, it tries to request a random URL. I've tested and Firefox neither restores the RNG state nor fakes the return value of `new Date()`. I chose to go with the latter because no collisions are possible (or if it does happen, then the code triggered in the same millisecond as the original response, in which case I'm also happy for it to show "Loaded 0s ago"). This behavior leads me to assume that Firefox' response faking works by matching the URL against a cache. By varying the URL, it does not find a cache entry and gives a network error instead. We then catch this network error and override the `dataLoaded` value to indicate "yup, that was a cached response".

The fallback is imperfect in that the original request might have worked but this `cachedetector` request might happen at a time where the network is down or otherwise fails. Thankfully, thanks to Kaiido, this is only a fallback.